# Check if an element in a list has a value in a defined position

Tags: python, list, indexing, sum, find

I am looking for a way to automate the process where I only add elements that have certain values in a very specific position of the list value. I know it sounds complicated, but I try to explain myself better in this trivial example:
I have all these indexes:

```
["0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"]
```

I want to sum all the indexes that they have 0 or 1 in position x and 0 or 1 in position y. In this case I want to sum all counts that they have 0 in position 1 (from right) and 1 in position 0 (from right) in their index

```
"01": counts["0001"] + counts["0101"] + counts["1001"] + counts["1101"]
```

To make more understandable, in this case I sum all counts that they have 1 in position 1 (from right) and 0 in position 0 in their index.

```
"10": counts["0010"] + counts["0110"] + counts["1010"] + counts["1110"]
```

Can I find an automatization to do this in Python?

**EDIT**:
I'll try to be more specific:

`counts = {'0001': 0.0001220703125, '0010': 0.000244140625, '0100': 0.0003662109375, '0101': 0.245849609375, '0110': 0.2486572265625, '0111': 0.000244140625, '1000': 0.0009765625, '1001': 0.2508544921875, '1010': 0.252197265625, '1101': 0.00048828125, '0000': 0.0, '0011': 0.0, '1011': 0.0, '1100': 0.0, '1110': 0.0, '1111': 0.0}`

What I need for example is get all index that they have 00 in the middle (position 1 and 2). So I need to select: '0001', '1000', '1001', '0000' which contains 0 in position 1 and 0 in position 2. And I want to sum all these values. '1101' is not good, because contains in order, 1 in position 0, 0 in position 1, 1 in position 2 and 1 in position 3.

The only things I know is the values of what I want (they are 2 which can take the values 0 or 1) and their position (which is 0 or 1 or 2, or 3).

I hope I was clear

Comment: `sum (k.endswith("01") for k in yourlist)`? for other conditions  `sum (k[2]=="1" and k[0]=="0" for k in yourlist)` - you sum the truthy values of whatever condition you have. True == 1 so the sum == the amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you can use slice notation, which lets you index from the right, as well as a list comprehension.

Indexing from the right works like this:

input:

```
my_string = '1001'
my_string[-3:-1]
```

output:

```
'00'
```

This is because [-3:] starts indexing in the third position from the right, and [:-1] indexes up to but not including the last position in the right.

Next, you want to sum all elements that are in your dictionary for which the key meets this condition. You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
sum([counts[key] for key in counts.keys() if key[-3:-1] == '00'])
0.251953125
```

Breaking this into steps:

```
[counts[key] for key in counts.keys()]
```

This creates a new list that has all the values of your original list. Not useful on its own.

But by adding in the conditional: "if key[-3:-1] == '00'", we filter down the list to only having the values where the third from the right and second from the right, what you're calling position 2 and position 1, are both '0'.

Thus, the new list only has values from the keys you're selecting for, and then we sum those values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's not what I want, look soon at the modified question.

Comment: Hey, did this work for you? Of so please accept the answer, and if not let me know how to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your indexes are of a dictionary. I'm creating a new one here based on the indexes. My code would look something like the following, making use of the `filter` function to filter the dictionary by index.

```
testlist = ["0000", "0001", "0010", "0011", "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111", "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011", "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111"]
testdict = {}

to_add_end = "10"

for binary in testlist:
    testdict[binary] = int(binary)

filtered_dict = dict(filter(lambda entry:entry[0][-len(to_add_end):] == to_add_end, testdict.items()))
print(sum(filtered_dict.values()))
```

The lambda function we pass to `filter`:

`lambda entry:entry[0][-len(to_add_end):] == to_add_end`

It tells the filter to only keep elements where the last n letters `[-len(to_add_end):]` of the first part `[0]` aka the key match the ending we want to keep.

Comment: But if I want to sum all indexes that they have 10 in position 1 and 2 from right? From all indexes I need to keep 0100, 1100, 1101, 0101 (assuming n=4)

Comment: then you reverse the `to_add_end` text

Comment: I can generally recommend starting to work with binary if that goes deeper

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
counts = {'0001': 0.0001220703125, '0010': 0.000244140625, '0100': 0.0003662109375, '0101': 0.245849609375, '0110': 0.2486572265625, '0111': 0.000244140625, '1000': 0.0009765625, '1001': 0.2508544921875, '1010': 0.252197265625, '1101': 0.00048828125, '0000': 0.0, '0011': 0.0, '1011': 0.0, '1100': 0.0, '1110': 0.0, '1111': 0.0}

def addcts(keystr, x, xv, y, yv):
    if x > len(keystr) or y > len(keystr):
        return False
    if keystr[x] == str(xv) and keystr[y] == str(yv):
        return True
    return False

print(sum([kel[1] for kel in counts.items() if addcts(kel[0], 2, 1, 3, 0)])) # 1 at position 2 and 0 at position 3
```

which results in `0.5010986328125` (the result you are looking for)?

**EDIT**: changed based on input from comment

Comment: Not exactly. Look at this
`countsC1 = {
            "00": counts["0000"] + counts["0100"] + counts["1000"] + counts["1100"],
            "01": counts["0001"] + counts["0101"] + counts["1001"] + counts["1101"],
            "10": counts["0010"] + counts["0110"] + counts["1010"] + counts["1110"],
            "11": counts["0011"] + counts["0111"] + counts["1011"] + counts["1111"]
 }`
I separated these from a dimension 4 to a dimension 2.Considering that the position of the pair for example 00 can vary, for example I want to sum all those index of dimension 4 that have 0 in position 1 and 2